# Convert Hex to Ascii in URL (in Scala)

Tags: string, scala, ascii, hex

I got this String "`&TOKEN=EC%2d1NK66318YB717835M`" as result from a WebService and I need to use it to complete my treatement but the issue is that I need to convert `%2d` to its Ascii value which is `-`. So my String will be is the end "`&TOKEN=EC-1NK66318YB717835M`"

How do i perform this with scala ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This encoding is called [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). In Scala, you can just use the Java class `java.net.URLDecoder` to decode it.

```
val url = "...&TOKEN=EC%2d1NK66318YB717835M..."
val s = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Actually `decode(String)` is deprecated. You should use `decode(String, String)`.

Comment: @ShyJ Fixed; note also that the API docs say that you must pass UTF-8  as the encoding, otherwise it might "introduce incompatibilities"...

Comment: @Jesper That's exactly what I did in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567545/convert-hexa-to-ascii-in-scala/13567748#answer-13567829)

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to know a little java. Use `java.net.URLDecoder` to decode your String. 
`java.net.URLDecoder.decode("&TOKEN=EC%2d1NK66318YB717835M")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [URLDecoder.decode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), like this:

```
import java.net.URLDecoder

object Main extends App {
    val s = "&TOKEN=EC%2d1NK66318YB717835M"
    val converted = URLDecoder.decode (s, "UTF-8")
    System.out.println (converted)
}
```

And a [fiddle](http://ideone.com/o2bF0o) for it